# Can we use "prava" for non-living organisms?

Tags: word-usage

I read this sentence *Lia opinio estas prava*. I found this sentence very weird, because I would write *Lia opinio estas ĝusta, ĉar li pravas*. Is this a way to speak more quickly, an error that become canon? Or can we use *prava* for other things than living organisms who can have opinions?

Answer (score 4):

The *Universala Vortaro* gives

> qui a raison, qui est dans le vrai | right (to be in the right) | Recht habend | правый (напр. я правъ) | mający słuszność.

The words *пра́вый, słuszność* can refer both to "correctness" and "righteousness" (among other things).

Examples of Zamenhof's usage show that he intended it to mean "justified, in the right" chiefly in the sense of being correct about something, but with a tinge of being morally right, and also as applicable to inanimate things ("justifiable"):

> Ĉiuj paroloj pri deveno kaj hereda sango estas nur frazoj kaj pretekstoj, por **pravigi niajn sentojn**, kiuj efektive havas tute alian bazon. *(Gentoj kaj Lingvo Internacia, 1911)*
>
> El ĉiuj projektoj, kiuj en diversaj tempoj estis proponitaj al la mondo, ofte sub la laŭta, **per nenio pravigita nomo** de « lingvo tutmonda », neniu solvis pli ol unu el la diritaj problemoj, kaj eĉ tiun ĉi nur parte. *(Unua Libro)*

Answer (score 2):

To me that sentence sounds weird as well. In PIV I found the following:

> **prav/a**
>   **1** Havanta opinion konforman al la vero: *ne tiu, kiu plej laŭte krias, estas pravaᶻ; li estas prava en sia procesoᶻ; vi estos gramatike tute pravaᶻ.*
>   **2** (pp opinio) Konforma al la vero: *li senkulpigis sin per la plej pravaj motivoj.* ☞ ĝusta.

Therefore, it seems that one can only use *prava* if one speaks of opinions. Since only living organisms can have opinions, one can only use *prava* for living organisms.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can and actually do use *prava* for non-living organisms, regardless of the definition found in dictionaries. 
Some examples from [Tekstaro](http://www.tekstaro.com/):

> **1** Do, mia konjekto pravis.
>
> **2** Sed tre certe tiu teorio pravas, kiam ĝi konkludas, ke...
>
> **3** Serĝento O’Cay estas sendube konfuza homo, sed, se ĉi tiu suspekto
>   pravas, tiam li ne estas kulpa.
>
> **4** — Ĉiu vorto pravas! — fanatikis la virino.
>
> **5** Sed pri kio MONATO pravis, estas, ke la vortoj estas malofte
>   kompreneblaj...